# no cycles f12 render or viewport with RTX 4090

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Just built 1/27/23 a Win 11, AMD 7059x, 128gb RAM, RTX 4090 PC all software is up to date. Will not f12 render or viewport render in Cycles. Object/sceen not there. Tried to many things to list.

Question: Can you use 4090 with benders cycles?

thanks

Comment: Sure you can use an RTX 4090 with Cycles. It's the fastest GPU at the moment. [opendata.blender.org](https://opendata.blender.org/benchmarks/query/?device_name=NVIDIA%20GeForce%20RTX%204090&compute_type=OPTIX&compute_type=CUDA&compute_type=HIP&compute_type=METAL&compute_type=ONEAPI&group_by=blender_version) has over 1200 benchmarks for it. Your question is hard to answer because there are many reasons why an F12 render doesn't work. Can you render the default cube? Does the scene look ok in the viewport? What does the render output look like? Black screen? Which render settings do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution (or error). I had set OptiX as my Cycles Render device selection in preferences/system. Today I was installing and testing the latest version of BoxCutter/HardOps -- Switching to Cycles left Blender hanging. After some time the white screen went back into an active Blender window, but no lights being rendered in the preview. I noticed a small message at the top left of the blender GUI:

> Requested OSL group data size (2112) is greater than the maximum
> supported with Optix (2048)

This prompted me to go into the preferences and switch the Cycles Render device from OptiX to CUDA. And now everything is working smooth as butter.